# How to convert sql result array of arrays to array of objects in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a simple sql query which returns the result as JSON arrays.But i want the output to be array of objects.How to get the expected format.

```
def data= cust.executeQuery("select custname,dept from customer")
println("data format:"+data);

Output:

Data:[[X,Sales],[Y,Finance]]

Expected format to be:

Data:[
 {Name:X,Dept:Sales},
 {Name:Y,Dept:Finance}
]
```

Comment: possible because you are not using `new map` in your HQL statement so by default you should get exactly what you want all you need to do is change `"select new map (custname as name,dept as department) from customer"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can achieve your goal with:

```
data.collect { [Name: it[0], Dept: it[1]] }
```

I tested it whith `[["X", "Sales"], ["Y", "Finance"]].collect { [Name: it[0], Dept: it[1]] }` and it does return a list of maps in given format.

Comment: Hi suricatta i tried the above logic but it didnot work for me.